# Implemented basic, auth bow left with no open page. Everything req auth?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, basic-authentication

I followed Bjorns well written tutorial on Basic auth, http://blog.smithfamily.dk/2008/08/27/ImplementingBasicAuthenticationInASPNET20.aspx, but now every page requires auth.

What I wanted to have is my Home controller open and free, also Login and Register. I tought they would be and that I could secure the parts needed with:

```
[Authorize]
        public ActionResult Test()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

My system.web looks like:

```
<authentication mode="None" />
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?" />
    </authorization>
```

and system.webServer:

```
<modules>
      <add name="BasicAuthHttpModule" type="TestProj.Modules.BasicAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
```

Any clues on how I can define open pages and locked down pages that requires a login to get inn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `AllowAnonymous` action filter to avoid the authentication for an action. For sample:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{

}
```

Or in your controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  // all actions would allow anonymous users
}
```